# Include NULL values in Range Query Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have framed Range query as below - Java High Level REST Client

```
QueryBuilder rangeQu = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("price").gt(30).lt(5000);
```

In this I want to include NULL/Empty values as well. How to include it?

Comment: Combine your query with a "not exists"-Query via boolean-"OR". https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Comment: I understand from elastic query but need to know how to do with Java High Level REST client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a bool query that takes either the range query or the not exist should work something like this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryFilter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
queryFilter.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("price").gt(30).lt(5000));
queryFilter.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("price")));
```